# Windows Phone Emulator accessing a server behind VPN

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, vpn

I am working on a Windows Phone app where the server I need to communicate with is only accessible if I connect to a VPN using OpenVPN. The VPN works fine, I can access the server using say a browser on my computer.

The problem is, that Windows Phone Emulator does not "see" the network I am connected to using VPN.

In the old Windows Phone 7, when disabled wifi and data on a device and connected it to a computer using a USB cable, the device used the computer to connect to the internet. But this no longer works with Windows Phone 8 (8.1) devices. The Windows Phone 8.1 build-in VPN is too primitive and does not work with the VPN I need to use.

Is there any way I can develop and app that needs to connect to a server only accessible through VPN.

Comment: `To disable automatic proxy detection on the host computer
On the host computer, open Internet Options from the Control Panel. The Internet Properties dialog box opens.
In the Internet Properties dialog box, click the Connections tab.
On the Connections page, click the LAN settings button. The Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog box opens.
In the Local Area Network (LAN) Settings dialog box, deselect all the check boxes. Click OK twice to close both dialog boxes.
Restart the emulator and retry the connection.`